# Removing Lower/Upper Fence of outliers from input data to then be evaluated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics

What I have attempted:

```
AVERAGEIF(B11:V11,">+MEDIAN(B11:V11)")
```

What I am trying to do:
I would like to take the average of the upper half of given data. Elaborating more. I would like to find a formula that will allow me to remove a given lower fence of outliers and dissect the data then given to me. I would greatly prefer to maintain this formula within one cell "not grabbing different results from formulas within multiple cells".

---

**Update:**

Following through I found the solution.. I think.

One thing I should have explained further:
 The data coming in replicating a typical sqrt function. 
 What I wanted to achieve is to capture the mean of the "plateau" of the data.

The equation I used was:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B3:B62,(">"&+TRIMMEAN(B3:B62,0.8)),B3:B62)
```

*This was something I just copied and pasted. of course "B3" and "B62" are significant only for my application.*

My rough explanation of the equation:

TRIMMEAN will limit the AVERAGE to the top 20%(">")(0.8) of the data selected.       So for my application, this SHOULD give me a rough mean of the "plateau" of the data i would like to find the mean for.

Comment: Sample data with expected outliers goes a long way to clarifying what you want to implement.  Right now it's all a bit abstract.  How exactly do you want to achieve "data that has been cleansed from unknown outliers" ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the average, if the number is greater than the median of those numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula calculates the Median() of the range, then AverageIf() uses the median and only grabs values that are greater than or equal to >= the median ~ giving you the average of the 'top-half' of your values.

```
AVERAGEIF(A1:A10,">="&MEDIAN(A1:A10))
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry I am responding months later. I ended up using: